# Flask framework for a small and medium size projects

Tags: python, flask

I'm about to try Flask framework and look if it fits my needs. I worked with Django, it is cool, but I want to try Flask. I have one small and maybe one medium-sized project and wanted to ask if Flask is the right framework to use for those?

Do you guys have experience by running medium-sized (or even large-scale) projects with Flask? Would be nice to hear facts and not just things like "I like Django because it is cool" or "I like Flask just because it is small" :)

Anyway, I will try to play with it, just from curiosity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flask works fine for larger applications, too.

Have a look at the ["Larger Applications" page of the flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/); it has some suggestions on how to keep your code properly structured.

If you need e.g. an ORM you can use [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://packages.python.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/) which nicely integrates SA into your Flask environment.

Comment: Great! Thanks ThiefMaster. Do you own or maintain larger Flask app by yourself? Maybe some statistics or some other nice things about Flask? Looks like really nice framework which gives a lot of freedom.

Comment: Depends on what you consider "large". My radio station's [website](https://www.radio-exodus.de) is built based on flask; it has more than 5k LOC of view functions.

Comment: And if we talk about the load? How good it is when we talk about the vistors per minute or pageviews? I do not ask you to give me your real  numbers, but just overal opinion :)

Comment: About 250k hits per month. However, performance issues caused by increasing visitor counts can be easily solved by caching things that can be cached. Especially things such as the front page which are usually hit most are good candidates for caching.

Comment: yes agree, I was also thinking about Redis or something like that. Thanks ThiefMaster. I think I got what I wanted :)

Comment: Yes, Flask works great for big applications, while it is a "micro" framework, it has a nice amount of available extensions, allowing you to "chose your weapons" (which is why I like flask btw). I usually end up with a Flask+Flask-SQLAlchemy+Flask-WTF+Flask-Login stack.

Answer (score 3):

Flask is great for all kind of projects. As long as you don't need Django's ORM (and all batteries like admin's pages), Flask is the right choice.

Comment: ORM is nice, but I have another idea how to live without ORM. Plus probably SQL Alchemy would help here. Thanks for comment!

Answer (score 0):

Normally I use Flask. But for rapid development I just wanted to build a project with Django however I didn't know it is a burden. When I don't want to use its default authentication mechanism and go with the things in my mind is hard to get rid of the built in structure.
On the other hand, using Flask is way more flexible and  maintainable. As I told I just wanted to do it for faster development but it took awhile to accept stiffness of Django. So it is not my personal favorite. Just wanted to write even this is an old post.